# Identify an Aromatic Plant

Tags: identification

Can anyone help to identify this plant? It is very fragrant when touched (strong sweet scent). Edges of leaves are smooth. Stems and undersides of leaves have downy soft white hair/fuzz. Leaves are very soft to touch (not stiff). Stems are round.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it have a square or rounded stem?  Where do you live?

Comment: Can you tell us about the flowers?

Answer (score 0):

I think its **common sage** (*salvia officianalis*) See [here](https://www.123rf.com/photo_18088002_plant-of-common-sage-salvia-officinalis-in-vegetable-garden.html) for a picture.

It's edible, of course  - as in "parsley, sage, rosemary and thyme..." It is the only seasoning used (in industrial quantities) in traditional Lincolnshire pork sausages in the UK - a proper Lincolnshire sausage should look green, not pink, because the quantity of sage in it! If your want to try cooking with it, beware that it does have quite a strong and unusual taste, though.

Comment: It isn't Salvia officinalis - that has slightly furry leaves and is greyer - I grow it and it doesn't look like this. Dunno what it actually is though...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes, this is definitely not sage. The smell reminds me of what stevia tastes like if that makes sense. I know it may not be edible, but I tried a very small nibble on a leaf and the taste is very mild (not bitter, just a hint of flavor, but definitely not sweet like stevia). I tried a handful of plant identification apps and none recognizes it. It smells so good, it must be known by someone.

Comment: @Kindah: if you think it is a wild plant, you should tell us (editing the question) in which region are you. I do not agree with Bamboo characteristic of Salvia: There are mow so many varieties, some not so whitish. But in any case that picture do not hit me on Salvia. I'll bet on Asteraceae.

Comment: The pictured plant has alternate leaves so it is probably not in the mint family (Lamiaceae) as that family usually has opposite leaves. A huge portion of aromatic herbs are in that family, so that excludes a large number of plants, including all *Salvia* species.